# How to find the formula for these repeating sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, trigonometry

How to find formula for this number pattern?

3,6,5,2,3,...

When plot this sequence into the graph, it is going to be the sine graph..

Comment: How does the rest of the sequence go? Is it $3,6,5,2,3,4,3,6,5, 4,4,\dots$? or is it $3,6,5,2,3,3,6,5,2,3,3,6,5,2,3,\dots$?

Comment: it is 3, 6, 5, 2, 3, 6, 5, 2, 3, 6, 5 ,2 and so on

Comment: $4-2\cos(\frac{n\pi}2)-\sin(\frac{n\pi}2)$

Comment: wowwww...How did you find it? Could you clarify the formula for me? Thank you so much :-)

Comment: The terms average out to $4$, so I "guessed" the formula would be $4+A\cos(\frac{n\pi}2)+B\sin(\frac{n\pi}2)$, and then it was easy to solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Is there a name for this formula? Is it related to the one that I mentioned above? the sine one.. I'm soooo sorry to bother you..

Answer (score 1):

There is no pattern. You can get any number you like to be the next in each sequence using infinitely many different formulae. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation for one type of formulae that can be made to fit any sequence.